# Custom Android sdk and unit test on Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to do a unit test with custom Android Sdk in Android Studio 2.2.2 with com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2. but I keep getting some errors and cannot get through them, so I would like to ask for your help. Let me explain what I’ve done and tried to see if you can figure it out and help me.

I did a custom android.jar extracting classes from Nexus 5x with android 6 (sdk 23). This jar contains hidden methods and internal classes.

#### COMPLETE CUSTOM SDK

The first attempt was creating a complete SDK. For that I downloaded the SDK, installed version 23 and replaced it in new_sdk/platform/android-23/android.jar with my custom jar.

In Android Studio I can execute tasks like assemble or install for generate apk, but when I execute a unitTest or any task that contains the ':app:mockableAndroidJar' task I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar' > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I think that I get this error because the custom sdk contains implementations in the methods and no Stubs like original android.jar.

#### CUSTOM SDK LIKE JAR DEPENDENCY

The second attempt I’ve tried is using the original sdk and add the extended custom sdk like dependency jar. In this case I add the jar in app build.gradle like:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   provided files('libs/android-full-23-nexus5x.jar')
   ...
}
```

AndroidStudio shows compilation error for hide methods and constants because can't resolve symbols, but it works for internal classes.

[image]

The problem is that Android Sdk overrides my custom jar. To fix this I’ve changed in *app.iml* the order of dependencies so:

```
...
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="android-full-23-nexus5x" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 23 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK"/>
...
```

[image]

This is a problem, because in each gradle sync *app.iml* is reordered.

Now, assemble or install tasks failed in compilation time too.

```
/.../MainActivity.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
    boolean aa = TelephonyManager.EMERGENCY_ASSISTANCE_ENABLED;
                                 ^
    symbol:   variable EMERGENCY_ASSISTANCE_ENABLED
    location: class TelephonyManager
/.../MainActivity.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
    String result = tm.getNai();
                      ^
    symbol:   method getNai()
    location: variable tm of type TelephonyManager
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

That is solved adding in *root* build.gradle :

```
allprojects {
   ...
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs.add("-Xbootclasspath/p:app/libs/android-full-23-nexus5x.jar")
       }
    }
}
```

After sync, clean and rebuild, assemble and install tasks works, only for actual BuildType but it works.

Now, I execute a unitTest without Mocks like:

```
public class EmailValidatorTest {
    @Test
    public void emailValidator_CorrectEmailSimple_ReturnsTrue() {
        assertTrue(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name@email.com"));
    }
}
```

This works ok, but when I need to execute a unitTest with mocks this fails:

```
public class MockUnitTest {

    private static final String FAKE_STRING = "my_app_name";

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    @Test
    public void readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
        // Given a mocked Context injected into the object under test...
        when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.app_name)).thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);
        ClassUnderTest myObjectUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mMockContext);

        // ...when the string is returned from the object under test...
        String result = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString();

        // ...then the result should be the expected one.
        assertThat(result, is(FAKE_STRING));
    }
}
```

.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
          at android.content.Context.getString(Unknown Source)
          at com.caseonit.pruebamockito.MockUnitTest.readStringFromContext_LocalizedString(MockUnitTest.java:32)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
          at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
          at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
          at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
          at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
          at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
          at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
          at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
          at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
          at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
          at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
          at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
          at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
          at org.mockito.internal.runners.SilentJUnitRunner.run(SilentJUnitRunner.java:39)
          at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
          at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:103)
          at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
          at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
          at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
          at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
          at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I have discovered that if I remove from the file *app.iml* the line `<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="android-full-23-nexus5x" level="project" />` unitTest with mock works and assemble task keeps working, the problem is that AndroidStudio shows error because can't resolve symbols.
This will also not allow mock hidden methods.

#### Executing unit test from command line

When AndroiStudio executes a unitTest the command is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin" -Didea.junit.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar: ... :.../app/libs/android-full-23-nexus5x.jar: ... :.../build/generated/mockable-android-23.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.caseonit.pruebamockito.MockUnitTest,readStringFromContext_LocalizedString
```

and the result is the same error from AndroidStudio, but if I change the **classpath** parameter and set the *android-full-23-nexus5x.jar* after **mockable-android-23.jar* the result is correct.

So, my question is: Is it posible to change classpath for unitTest? I have tried

```
android.unitTestVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.javaCompile.classpath.minus(['/.../app/libs/android-full-23-nexus5x.jar'])
}
```

or similar, but none works.
Do you have any idea or suggestion?
Thank you very much. 
Best regards,